# Unexpected Java Text Output

Tags: java

When I run this code, it outputs `blockA blockB blockA`.

I expected the output to be `blockB blockA blockA`.

Why is the output `blockA blockB blockA`, not `blockB blockA blockA`?

```
public class Test
{
    public static Test t1 = new Test();
    {
        System.out.println("blockA");
    }
    static
    {
        System.out.println("blockB");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t2 = new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: The variables are initialized before the static block. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 2):

Here In class, you have put following statement first.

```
public static Test t1 = new Test();
```

So it will be execute class initializer

```
{
        System.out.println("blockA");
}
```

So  **blockA** will be printed.

Then static initializer is executed

```
   static
    {
        System.out.println("blockB");
    }
```

and **blockB** is printed

finally code inside main function is executed

```
 Test t2 = new Test();
```

and that will trigger class initializer again

```
{
        System.out.println("blockA");
}
```

and so **blockA** is printed again.

A detailed description about execution order about class and static initializer is  here [jls-12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)